# Pycharm is Stopping on unknown breakpoints in debug mode

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using pycharm for development in my django based project. In debug mode, Pycharm keep on stopping the execution of code on the place where I have not put any breakpoint. These breakpoints are in the core code of packages which I have in my requirement.txt file and required in my project and not in the code of my project. How can I solve this problem?

Below is the snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pycharm does not show breakpoints which we add in core code of packages. To remove these breakpoints click button highlighted bellow.

[image]

You will get list of breakpoints in your project. You can remove them from there.