# PyCharm 2016.2 Automatic breakpoints

Tags: python, django, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm getting some 'odd' behaviour out of the debugger in PyCharm 2016.2. Whenever I make a change and the server restarts, I have a few automated breakpoints that always trigger. Specifically, it seems that I always get a break point at **line 1226 in python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py** and **line 549 python2.7/os.py**

I've removed all manual breakpoints that I set, and in Run -> View Breakpoints, I've made sure that both Python Exception breakpoint and Django Exception breakpoint don't have the 'enabled/suspend' boxes checked.

Not sure if there are any changes to this version of PyCharm that would cause this to halt on those lines, but I can't seem to find any way to stop that from happening. Has anyone had this before?

Below are the details of my version:

> PyCharm 2016.2
>
> Build #PY-162.1237.1, built on July 20, 2016
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 amd64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Running on

> Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: In the debug window, you can see two overlapping red dots next to two white(ish) dots. click this, and you'll find that some are probably being raised on an exception?... Not sure what you're asking about exactly

Comment: That's what I've done -- there's no exception and I disabled halting on Python exceptions anyway to test -- that's where my confusion is.

Comment: Check this issue. This may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820835/pycharm-is-stopping-on-unknown-breakpoints-in-debug-mode

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @MHassan , unfortunately that's what I've tried and I removed all system breakpoints as well, but the process still halts. I have taken these screenshots of my breakpoint menu, see [here](http://imgur.com/a/S2cHV) for details. Thanks again for your help, I may be doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in PyCharm, Yet to be resolved. Refer this link.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20442

Comment: What I was looking for. I checked YouTrack before asking here but there wasn't anything at the time. Thanks!